# Reeses "Game Changer" commercial: Copyright infringement

Tags: copyright

If you watch the commercial you'll notice that the half eaten Reeses cup is imitating a (Mr.) PACMAN eating the Reeses pieces as Pac man pellets. In the nature of the game, Pac man is constantly making turns to avoid ghosts and consume all pellets. In the commercial the Pacman look alike never makes a turn.

https://youtu.be/lYH19IVlumw

So were they just editing the commercial and we never see a turn? Or were they trying to avoid copyright infringement by not ever showing the impression turning as signature to the game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [bottom of the video near the beginning](https://youtu.be/lYH19IVlumw?t=1), they clearly credit the Pac-Man trademark and Bandai Namco Entertainment Inc, so presumably they have a license from Bandai Namco to use the likeness of Pac-Man.

Comment: It's not necessary to get a license to use a trademark.  The use of the Pac-Man trademark to sell food is probably not trademark infringement.

Comment: @phoog That was my other thought, but I'm not confident to say whether or not this would fall under trademark fair use.